# Fast Partition of list at depth 2

Tags: performance-tuning, partitions

I am looking to partition a list up at a certain depth level. Following code should demonstrate what I mean:

```
test = Table[Random[], {1000}, {32}, {32}];

result = Map[Partition[#, {5, 5}, 1] &, test]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.5200297, Null} *)
```

This does what I want, but is there a faster way?

Thanks,
Julian.

Comment: Probably `Partition[test, {1, 5, 5}, 1]`, except it introduces an unneeded extra layer of braces. (Unfortunately, I am not near a machine to check.)

Comment: Actually that's twice as slow.

Comment: @Chris it's a bit faster on my machine. 0.52sec vs 0.44sec.

Answer (score 1):

```
test = RandomReal[{}, {5000, 32, 32}];
cf = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}}, 
   Evaluate@Quiet@Partition[Table[A[[i, j]], {i, 32}, {j, 32}], {5, 5}, 1], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> Listable];

result1 = Partition[#, {5, 5}, 1] & /@ test; // AbsoluteTiming
result2 = cf@test; // AbsoluteTiming
result1 === result2
```

[image]

Comment: On my system, 10.1.0 under Windows 7 x64, timings are 0.706 vs 0.137 so your code is 5X faster, and that is without compilation to C.  Well done!